# Returning Time Components with Modulus

Tags: time, modulo, epoch

Someone does 20 Hours 42 Minutes & 16 Seconds in one shift totaling 74536 seconds.
How do I get the hours from number of seconds the person has done for that shift?

```
20 * 60 * 60      =    72000
     42 * 60      =     2520
          16      =       16
                  +    -----
Total             =    74536
____________________________
Total % 60        =  Seconds (16)
Total % ?         =  Minutes (42)
Total % ?         =    Hours (20)
```

Tried 84600 already; turns out when a number is lower the modulus, it really is not very helpful, and something I am going to have to catch should someone only sign in for a few seconds ...

Comment: NB: 74536 % 3600 = 2536.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use both modulus and division:

```
t = seconds_in_shift;
secs = t % 60;
t /= 60;
mins = t % 60;
t /= 60;
hour = t;
```

Or:

```
secs =  ttime % 60;
mins = (ttime / 60) % 60;
hour =  ttime / 3600;
```

One other option uses the [`div()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/div.html) function from Standard C (`<stdlib.h>`):

```
div_t v1 = div(ttime, 60);
div_t v2 = div(v1.quot, 60);
```

After that, `v1.rem` contains the seconds; `v2.rem` contains the minutes, and `v2.quot` contains the hours based on the number of seconds originally in `ttime`.

Comment: And then just floor the results, or cast to int.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Jonathan's reply, I believe the accurate answer should be this…

```
$total_time = 61000;
$sec = $total_time % 60;
$total_time = ($total_time - $sec) / 60;
$min = $total_time % 60;
$hour = ($total_time - $min) / 60;
echo "$hour hours, $min minutes and $sec seconds";
```

But if your server has PHP7 installed, you can use the [intdiv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intdiv.php) function. An integer division in which the remainder is discarded.

```
// $hour = ($total_time - $min) / 60; old code but still works
$hour = intdiv($total_time, 60); // PHP7 and above code
```